# Alternative to selectivizr.js

Tags: javascript, selectivizr

The [selectivizr.js](https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr) project's last update is a year ago and with many PR & Issues.

Is there any better alternative to selectivizr.js?

Comment: Some great resources here that may prove useful http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-and-css3-without-guilt/

Comment: [ie7-js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) by Dean Edwards is a good alternative, but it also suffers from not supporting DOM modifications (ajax loaded content).

Comment: see this [selectivizr2: Selectivizr with maintenance](https://github.com/corysimmons/selectivizr2) (more up to date)